# Dealing with generic entities managed by Hibernate when migrating from Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, migration

We migrate from Spring v2.7.x to v3.2.2 which implies the migration from Hibernate v5.x. to v6.4.4.Final. As a DB we (have to) use H2 v2.2.224. We have the following domain model structure beginning with generic entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class EntityBase implements Serializable {

    private Long id;
    protected UUID uuid;

    public EntityBase() {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    protected void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.CHAR)
    public UUID getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    protected void setUuid(final UUID uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    //getters, setters etc.
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FachparameterBaseReference")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class FachparameterBaseReference<FACHID extends FachparameterFachId<FACHID>> extends EntityBase {
  protected FACHID fachId;

  //other fields

  @Transient
  public FACHID getFachId(){
    return fachId;
  }
    //setter for fachId, getters/setters etc. for other fields.
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FachparameterReference")
public abstract class FachparameterReference<FACHID extends FachparameterFachId<FACHID>, FACHCODE extends FachparameterFachCode<FACHCODE>>
            extends FachparameterBaseReference<FACHID> {

  private FACHCODE fachCode;

  @Transient
  public FACHCODE  getFachCode(){
    return fachCode;
  }

  @Override
    public FACHID getFachId() {
        return fachId;
    }

  //setters for FACHID, FACHCODE, other fields with getters/setters etc.
}
```

Further we have a couple of specific entities which extend the above mentioned generic ones respectively. Below are **two** examples of each generic entity type (FachparameterReference and FachparameterBaseReference):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ZuordnungReference")
public class ZuordnungReference extends FachparameterBaseReference<ZuordnungFachId> {
  private ZuordnungFachId fachId;

  @Convert(converter = ZuordnungFachIdConverter.class)
  @Override
  public ZuordnungFachId getFachId() {
   return fachId;
  }

  //other fields with getters/setters and setter for fachId
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MessungReference")
public class MessungReference extends FachparameterBaseReference<MessungFachId> {
  private MessungFachId fachId;

  @Convert(converter = MessungFachIdConverter.class)
  @Override
  public MessungFachId getFachId() {
   return fachId;
  }

  //other fields with getters/setters and setter for fachId
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FehlerReference")
public class FehlerReference extends FachparameterReference<FehlerFachId, FehlerFachCode> {

  private FehlerFachId fachId;
  private FehlerFachCode fachCode;

  @Convert(converter = FehlerFachIdConverter.class)
  @Override
  public FehlerFachId getFachId() {
   return fachId;
  }

  @Convert(converter = FehlerFachCodeConverter.class)
  @Override
  public FehlerFachCode getFachCode() {
    return fachCode;
  }

//other fields with getters/setters and setters for fachId and fachCode
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FunktionReference")
public class FunktionReference extends FachparameterReference<FunktionFachId, FunktionFachCode> {


  private FunktionFachId fachId;
  private FunktionFachCode fachCode;

  @Convert(converter = FunktionFachIdConverter.class)
  @Override
  public FunktionFachId getFachId() {
   return fachId;
  }

  @Convert(converter = FunktionFachCodeConverter.class)
  @Override
  public FunktionFachCode getFachCode() {
    return fachCode;
  }

//other fields with getters/setters and setters for fachId and fachCode
```

Then we have the following generic repositories:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface FachparameterBaseRepository<FACHID extends FachparameterFachId<FACHID>, ENTITY extends FachparameterBaseReference<FACHID>>
            extends JpaRepository<ENTITY, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT f FROM #{#entityName} f WHERE f.fachId = :fachId")
    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = HibernateHints.HINT_FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") })
    Optional<ENTITY> findByFachId(FACHID fachId);
}
```

```
public interface FachparameterRepository<FACHID extends FachparameterFachId<FACHID>, FACHCODE extends FachparameterFachCode<FACHCODE>, ENTITY extends FachparameterReference<FACHID, FACHCODE>>
            extends FachparameterBaseRepository<FACHID, ENTITY> {

    
    @Deprecated
    @Query("SELECT f FROM #{#entityName} f WHERE f.fachCode = :fachcode")
    @QueryHints(value = { @QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.FLUSH_MODE, value = "COMMIT") })
    Optional<ENTITY> findByFachcode(FACHCODE fachcode);
}
```

`FachparameterFachId` and `FachparameterFachCode` are interfaces which have multiple implementations as Java record classes (each example below):

```
public interface FachparameterFachId<T extends FachparameterFachId<T>> extends CharSequence, Comparable<T>, Serializable {
  
String fachId();
}
```

```
public record FachparameterFachIdImpl(String fachId) implements FachparameterFachId<FachparameterFachIdImpl> {

    public FachparameterFachIdImpl {
        if (fachId.isBlank()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static FachparameterFachIdImpl of(final String value) {
        return new FachparameterFachIdImpl(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fachId();
    }
}
```

```
public interface FachparameterFachCode<T extends FachparameterFachCode<T>> extends CharSequence, Comparable<T>, Serializable {
  
String fachCode();
}
```

```
public record FachparameterFachCodeImpl(String fachCode) implements FachparameterFachCode<FachparameterFachCodeImpl> {

    public FachparameterFachCodeImpl {
        if (fachCode.isBlank()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

    public static FachparameterFachCodeImpl of(final String value) {
        return new FachparameterFachCodeImpl(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return fachCode();
    }
}
```

And to the last the following specific repositories (among a couple of other specific ones):

```
@Repository
public interface ZuordnungRepository
            extends FachparameterBaseRepository<ZuordnungFachId, ZuordnungReference> {
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface FehlerRepository extends FachparameterRepository<FehlerFachId, FehlerFachCode, FehlerReference> {

}
```

When starting the application the following exception is being raised:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional FachparameterRepository.findByFachcode(FachparameterFachCode)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:170)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:252)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111)
    ... 69 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.query.PathException: Could not resolve attribute 'fachCode' of 'FachparameterReference' due to the attribute being declared in multiple subtypes 'FunktionReference' and 'FehlerReference'
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy168.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:94)
    ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.PathException: Could not resolve attribute 'fachCode' of 'FachparameterReference' due to the attribute being declared in multiple subtypes 'FunktionReference' and 'FehlerReference'
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.EntityTypeImpl.findSubtypeAttribute(EntityTypeImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.EntityTypeImpl.findSubPathSource(EntityTypeImpl.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.SqmPathSource.getSubPathSource(SqmPathSource.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmPath.get(AbstractSqmPath.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.domain.AbstractSqmFrom.resolvePathPart(AbstractSqmFrom.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.DomainPathPart.resolvePathPart(DomainPathPart.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.consumeIdentifier(BasicDotIdentifierConsumer.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimplePath(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:5060)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitIndexedPathAccessFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:5009)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathFragment(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:4984)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitGeneralPathExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1776)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$GeneralPathExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:7699)
    at org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visitChildren(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParserBaseVisitor.visitBarePrimaryExpression(HqlParserBaseVisitor.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$BarePrimaryExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:7157)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.createComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2392)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6164)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.interpretHql(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:790)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:840)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

What are we missing? Why is this exception being raised? Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: Why voting for closing though? The vote states that an information is needed for reproducing the error. I think I provided enough stuff to reproduce it. If something is missing in somebody's opinion, just leave a comment and I'll do my best.